# Is there a grid for storing data?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I need to store data in a grid like this:

```
{0,1,2,3}
{4,5,6,7}
{8,9,10,11}
{12,13,14,15}
```

I know I can use multi dimensional arrays, but Is there any easier way to do it? Also I need to get values from it like myData.Item(0,1) would return 1.

Comment: I wonder what you think the difference between a multidimensional array and what you're suggesting is. By the way with a multidimensional array you could access the elements as `arr(0,1)`.

Comment: multidimensional arrays are pretty straightforward.. what do you think could be easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a list of [tuples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) if you are using .NET 4.0.

In this case, [Tuple(Of T1, T2, T3, T4)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd414846.aspx):

```
Dim matrix() =  
           { Tuple.Create(0,1,2,3),
             Tuple.Create(4,5,6,7),
             Tuple.Create(8,9,10,11),
             Tuple.Create(12,13,14,15)}
```

Comment: how this easier than a multi dimensional array? int[,] array = {{0, 1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6, 7}, {8, 9, 10, 11}, {12, 13, 14, 15}};

Comment: @Can - easier to create, no. Easier to access items (readability wise)? Possibly.

Comment: @Oded: Unless I'm missing something, this solution would only work if he's using the framework 4.0

Comment: @Claudio - no, you are not missing anything. The OP didn't specify a version.

Comment: The only way to access tuples is .Item1, .Item2 etc, and it's not even possible to iterate through them. Doesn't sound much better to me.

Comment: @Claudio - It's fairly simple to write your own Tuple class anyway.